# What is the step by step procedure to analyze automatic logout on a linux ( ubuntu) system

Tags: linux, bash, login, logout

After I login using UI, I am logged out.
Shall I start by looking on log files ? Which one.
I have root authority on the system.
Is putting a "pause" or "sleep" in a script file that gets executed during login or  logout is the place to start?  If yes, which file? 
Note: 1. If I login using terminal , I am fine. 
2. This is happening for every user.

Comment: It is unlikely that OS based file will cause havoc (and auto-logout). did you get same problem  with an unmodified user ? otherwise, use `set -x ` at beginning of files.

Comment: look `/var/log/message`, `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and `/var/log/secure`

Comment: It sounds like you're describing [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop): if so, I'd start by looking at your ~/.xsession-errors log and paying particular attention to the writeability of your ~/.Xauthority file

Comment: @archemar I referred to http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html nd came to know that it will print the output. How do I redirect it to a file. Will set -x > out.txt  work?

Comment: @steeldriver Should ~/.Xauthority be writable?

Comment: Yes it should be owned by and writeable by the user (usually mode 600 or `-rw-------`)

Comment: @Mongrel I could not find /var/log/message, /var/log/audit/audit.log and /var/log/secure in /var/log. The /var/log  has followings:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sources from various people were helpful in leading me to right direction. I examined `/var/log`. It had

```
alternatives.log
alternatives.log.1
bootstrap.log
kern.log
btmp
kern.log.1
btmp.1
unattended-upgrades/
apport.log
ConsoleKit/
upstart/
apport.log.1
cups/
wtmp
dist-upgrade/
lastlog
dmesg
lightdm/
Xorg.0.log
dmesg.0
nvidia-prime-upstart.log
prime-offload.log
Xorg.1.log
dpkg.log
prime-supported.log
samba/
apt/
speech-dispatcher/
auth.log
faillog
syslog
fontconfig.log
fsck/
gpu-manager.log
Xorg.failsafe.log
hp/
boot.log
installer/
```

Then I used: `ls -ltr` and saw that the first file modified for today ( after I attempted to login was) `nvidia-prime-upstart.log`.

`nvidia-prime-upstart.log` had this line "Sorry but your hardware configuration is not supported." Now I wanted to list all packaged that had "nvidia" in name. I used `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`. Then I uninstalled the unneeded packages. The reason of unneeded packages was that I had installed nvidia driver and cuda programming packages in a blind enthusiasm to learn CUDA programming!